# Bash Script Result Different via Cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I'm relatively new to bash scripting, but I've written a small script that is supposed to check the status of a service and restart it if it isn't running. The setup in cron is fine and it is running, the issue I'm having is the setting of the variable "STATUS" as shown in the code below.  When I run the script from prompt it runs fine, but when it runs via cron the STATUS variable doesn't get set. Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

STATUS=$(service nagios status)
DATE=$(date)

if [ "$STATUS" == "No lock file found in /var/run/nagios.pid" ]
then
service nagios start
echo "$DATE - Stopped - $STATUS" >> /var/log/nagios/nagios_check.log
elif [ "$STATUS" == "nagios is not running" ]
then
service nagios start
echo "$DATE - Stopped - $STATUS" >> /var/log/nagios/nagios_check.log
else
echo "$DATE - Running - $STATUS" >> /var/log/nagios/nagios_check.log
fi
```

Comment: You need to set the PATH in the script or use the ful path of programs, like `STATUS=$(/usr/sbin/service nagios status)`

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do is check your paths. Your cron environment has a minimal setup - it is not an emulation of your user BASH environment. You may want to use the full path for 'service', e.g.

```
STATUS=$(/usr/sbin/service nagios status)
```

For a more detailed description about cron BASH environments:
https://serverfault.com/questions/698577/why-is-the-cron-env-different-from-the-users-env

Comment: That did it. Changing to /sbin/service nagios status was the fix. Thanks for your help!